# Create chinese xml ruby nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am facing issue with nokogiri xml builder with Chinese characters.
This is working fine for
`<adjustment_type>temporary</adjustment_type`>

and fails for

```
<調整類型>temporary</調整類型>
```

I am doing it with

```
a = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.send "調整類型", "abc"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with use of insert

```
xml.send :insert , "<#{entity.name}>#{entity_value.value}</#{entity.name}>"
```